base::cumsum() not working anymore with dplyr::mutate_at() in R Sparklyr
Issue
I have to do a cumulative sum over several columns on a grouped and ordered (big) spark dataframe.
I used to do it with base::cumsum() and dplyr::mutate_at() and it worked fine. It does not work anymore with this session Info :
sessionInfo()
R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14)
spark_version = "3.5.0"
sparklyr_1.8.4    dbplyr_2.4.0      dplyr_1.1.4

Reproducible example
library("dplyr"); library("sparklyr"); library("dbplyr")
spark_version = "3.5.0"
sc = spark_connect(master = "local", version = spark_version)

# --- copying mtcars data into spark for the example
sdf_mtcars = sdf_copy_to(sc = sc, x = mtcars, name = "sdf_mtcars", overwrite = TRUE)

sdf_mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>%
  window_order(disp) %>%
  mutate_at(.vars = 'mpg', .funs = cumsum) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  collect()

but it generates the error  :
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `mpg = .Primitive("cumsum")(mpg)`
Caused by error in `mutate_at()`:
! object 'mpg' not found

It works fine if I use sum() over cumsum().
It alors works fine if I do :
mutate("mpg_cumulative" =  cumsum(mpg)) 

but I have to do it over several named columns inside a vector (like
: c('mpg') in my example)
It alors works fine if I do :
mutate_at(.vars = 'mpg', .funs = ~ cumsum(.)) %>%

but the syntax is a bit weird ?
Thank you.

Not an answer, but note that mutate_at and its siblings have been superseded by mutate(across(...)) in recent versions of dplyr. See, for example, here.

@Limey Yes but mutate_at() is not deprecated is it ?

@Friede I have to do it over several columns, not just mpg

I'm using Databricks so the setup is a little different, but it's Spark 3.5.0.
library("dplyr"); library("sparklyr"); library("dbplyr")
sc <- sparklyr::spark_connect(method = "databricks")
# just example output
mtcars %>% arrange(disp) %>% select(mpg, disp, cyl, drat) %>% head(10)
                    mpg  disp cyl drat
Toyota Corolla 33.9  71.1   4 4.22
Honda Civic    30.4  75.7   4 4.93
Fiat 128       32.4  78.7   4 4.08
Fiat X1-9      27.3  79.0   4 4.08
Lotus Europa   30.4  95.1   4 3.77
Datsun 710     22.8 108.0   4 3.85
Toyota Corona  21.5 120.1   4 3.70
Porsche 914-2  26.0 120.3   4 4.43
Volvo 142E     21.4 121.0   4 4.11
Merc 230       22.8 140.8   4 3.92

Now for the actual question. As recommended by @Limey, use dplyr::across.
sdf_mtcars = sdf_copy_to(sc = sc, x = mtcars, name = "sdf_mtcars", overwrite = TRUE)

sdf_mtcars %>% 
  select(mpg, disp, cyl, drat) %>% # just to reduce output
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  window_order(disp) %>%
  mutate(across(c(mpg, drat), cumsum)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  collect()

I also always recommend dplyr::show_query to make sure it's doing what you actually want:
sdf_mtcars %>% 
  select(mpg, disp, cyl, drat) %>% # just to reduce output
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  window_order(disp) %>%
  mutate(across(c(mpg, drat), cumsum)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  dplyr::show_query()

<SQL>
SELECT
  SUM(`mpg`) OVER (PARTITION BY `cyl` ORDER BY `disp` ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS `mpg`,
  `disp`,
  `cyl`,
  SUM(`drat`) OVER (PARTITION BY `cyl` ORDER BY `disp` ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS `drat`
FROM `sdf_mtcars`

Also, if you really want to use mutate_at, you just need to use tidyselect
sdf_mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>%
  window_order(disp) %>%
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(mpg, drat), .funs = cumsum) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  collect()

Lastly, this syntax ~ cumsum(.) is just the tidyverse style of anonymous functions, though technically it should be .funs = ~ cumsum(.x).
